# Filter out city, year and temp using pig?

Tags: apache-pig, hadoop2

Record :

```
Pune,2007,31.5
Pune,2007,30.5
Pune,2008,34.5
Blre,2009,13.0
Blre,2009,10.5
```

Script which I'm using :

```
grunt> A = LOAD '/home/cloudera/temp' using PigStorage(',') AS (city:chararray,year:int,temp:double);
grunt> B = group A by city;
grunt> C = FOREACH B GENERATE group, MAX(A.temp);
```

Output:

```
 Pune, 34.5
 Blre, 13.0
```

Expected Output:

```
 Pune, 2007, 31.5
 Pune, 2008, 34.5
 Blre, 2009, 13.0
```

How can I achieve this result, thanks in advance.

Comment: If answer helps please consider them as a solution by accepting the answer by clicking on the tick.

Answer (score 0):

Group by city and year.

```
A = LOAD '/home/cloudera/temp' using PigStorage(',') AS (city:chararray,year:int,temp:double);
B = group A by (city,year);
C = FOREACH B GENERATE FLATTEN(group) AS (city,year), MAX(A.temp);
```

Comment: Really Appreciate the quick one, Thank you.